# Set img src with Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have an input string which is html.  It contains images and I want to change the src property on the img

My code so far is as below:

```
       if (htmlStr.Contains("img"))
        {
            var html = new HtmlDocument();
            html.LoadHtml(htmlStr);

            var images = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");

            if (images != null && images.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
                {
                    string imageSrc = images[i].Attributes["src"].Value;
                    string newSrc = "MyNewValue";
                    images[i].SetAttributeValue("src", newSrc);
                }
            }

            //htmlStr=  ???
        }
        return htmlStr;
```

What I am missing is how to update the htmlStr I am returning with the newSrc value each image.

Comment: you try `html.ToString()`?

Comment: @zgood - no good shout - didnt even cross my mind that one of the most straightforward solutions would be the correct approach - l'll try it

Comment: @zgood - that sets htmlStr to "HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument" - I checked html.Text and html.ParsedText but neither or them have my img src updated to the MyNewValue string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you have two options:

```
// Will give you a raw string.
// Not ideal if you are planning to
// send this over the network, or save as a file.
var updatedStr = html.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;

// Will let you write to any stream.
// Here, I'm just writing to a string builder as an example.
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
{
    html.Save(writer);
}

// These two methods generate the same result, though.
Debug.Assert(string.Equals(updatedStr, sb.ToString()));
```

Comment: @grud - I had just coded the StringWriter option myself and was about to post it as my answer - think I will go with it and I have marked your answer as accepted